# Как увеличить масштаб редактора в qt creator на mac

Tags: qtcreator

Как увеличить масштаб редактора в qt creator на mac без мышки? Случайно уменьшил и не могу найти как[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ctrl + ~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @gbg не работает( пытался